Window is not defined even after 'use client', UseEffect(), and Next/Dynamic SSR: Disabled | NextJs 14
Here is my folder structure. The page is consisted of broken down client-side components, especially "hero.jsx".
enter image description here
In page.jsx or the main page, i imported all of these components and make sure that they're not SSR'd
page.jsx
**"use client";**
**import dynamic from "next/dynamic";**

import styles from "./page.module.css";
import LocomotiveScroll from "locomotive-scroll";
import { useEffect } from "react";

// Dynamically import components with SSR disabled
**const Hero = dynamic(() => import("./components/home/hero/hero"), {
  ssr: false,
});
const Services = dynamic(() => import("./components/home/services/services"), {
  ssr: false,
});
const Splash = dynamic(() => import("./components/splash/splash"), {
  ssr: false,
});
const Navbar = dynamic(() => import("./components/navbar/navbar"), {
  ssr: false,
});
**
const Home = () => {

  
  **useEffect(() => {**
  **  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {**
      const locomotiveScroll = new LocomotiveScroll();
      setIsClient(true)
   ** } **
      
  }, []);
  return (
    <main
      className={styles.main}
      style={{
        paddingBottom: "600px",
      }}
    >
      <Navbar></Navbar>
      <Splash></Splash>
      <Hero></Hero>
      <Services></Services>
    </main>
  );
};

export default Home;


and the animation happens in hero.jsx with window variable called
hero.jsx
**"use client";**
import styles from "./styles.module.css";
import Image from "next/image";
import gsap from "gsap";
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { ScrollTrigger } from "gsap/ScrollTrigger";

export default function Hero() {
  //ref for texts
  const bioText = useRef(null)
  const descText = useRef(null)
  const ctaText = useRef(null)

  //ref for sliders
  const firstList = useRef(null)
  const secondList = useRef(null)
  const slider = useRef(null)
  const textWeb = useRef(null)

  let xPercent = 0;
  let direction = -1;


**  useEffect(()=>{**

   ** if (typeof window !== "undefined") {**
      requestAnimationFrame(animation)
      gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger)
      const timeline = gsap.timeline()
  
      timeline
        .to(slider.current, {
          scrollTrigger: {
            trigger: document.documentElement,
            start: 0,
            end: **window**.innerHeight,
            scrub: 0.25,
            onUpdate: (e) => (direction = e.direction * -1),
          },
          // x:'-=300px'
        })
        .to([slider.current, textWeb.current], {
          duration: 2.5,
          clipPath: "inset(0% 0% 0% 0%)",
          ease: "power1.inOut",
        })
        .to(bioText.current, {
          duration: 1,
          clipPath: "inset(0% 0% 0% 0%)",
          ease: "power1.inOut",
        }, 1)
        .to(descText.current, {
          duration: 1,
          clipPath: "inset(0% 0% 0% 0%)",
          ease: "power1.inOut",
        }, 1)
        .to(ctaText.current, {
          duration: 1,
          clipPath: "inset(0% 0% 0% 0%)",
          ease: "power1.inOut",
        }, 1);
   ** }**


      
**  }, [])**

  const animation = () =>{
    if(xPercent <= -100){
      xPercent = 0;
    }
    if(xPercent > 0){
      xPercent = -100;
    }
    gsap.set(firstList.current, {
      xPercent: xPercent
    })
    gsap.set(secondList.current, {
      xPercent: xPercent
    })
    xPercent += 0.01 * direction;
    requestAnimationFrame(animation)


  }
  return (
    <div className={styles.hero}>
      <div className={styles.upperColumn}>
        <div ref={bioText} data-scroll data-scroll-speed='0.2' className={styles.textWrapper}>
        <div className={styles.profilePicture}>
          <Image
            src={"/images/pp rayyan.jpg"}
            fill={true}
            alt="profile picture rayyan"
          />
        </div>
        <p className={styles.mainParagraph}>
          Rayyan is a web designer, <span className={styles.bolderText}>combining the skills of a designer and a
          developer
            </span>.
        </p>
        </div>
        <div ref={ctaText} data-scroll data-scroll-speed='0.05' className={styles.textWrapper}>
        <p className={styles.mainParagraph}>Know more about him.</p>
        </div>
        
      </div>
      <div className={styles.midColumn}>
        <h1 ref={textWeb} className={styles.webText}>WEB</h1>
        <div ref={descText} className={styles.textWrapper}>
        <p className={styles.mainParagraph}>
          He is known for his web designs, animations, and interactions,
          utilizing his React expertise to implement prototypes.
        </p>
        </div>
        
      </div>
      <div className={styles.lowColumn}>
        <div data-scroll ref={slider} className={styles.slider}>
        <div  ref={firstList} className={styles.sliderList}>
          <h1>DESIGNER</h1>
          <div className={styles.svgContainer}>
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="182" height="182" viewBox="0 0 182 182" fill="none">
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M16.047 144.74L54.7868 106H0V76H54.7868L16.047 37.2602L37.2602 16.047L75.567 54.3538V0H105.567V55.2198L144.74 16.0463L165.954 37.2595L127.213 76H182V106H127.213L165.954 144.74L144.74 165.954L105.567 126.78V182H75.567V127.646L37.2602 165.953L16.047 144.74Z" fill="#FF4D00"/>
  </svg>
          </div>
          <h1>DEVELOPER</h1>
          <div className={styles.svgContainer}>
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="182" height="182" viewBox="0 0 182 182" fill="none">
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M16.047 144.74L54.7868 106H0V76H54.7868L16.047 37.2602L37.2602 16.047L75.567 54.3538V0H105.567V55.2198L144.74 16.0463L165.954 37.2595L127.213 76H182V106H127.213L165.954 144.74L144.74 165.954L105.567 126.78V182H75.567V127.646L37.2602 165.953L16.047 144.74Z" fill="#FF4D00"/>
  </svg>
          </div>
       
        </div>
        <div ref={secondList} className={styles.sliderList}>
          <h1>DESIGNER</h1>
          <div className={styles.svgContainer}>
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="182" height="182" viewBox="0 0 182 182" fill="none">
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M16.047 144.74L54.7868 106H0V76H54.7868L16.047 37.2602L37.2602 16.047L75.567 54.3538V0H105.567V55.2198L144.74 16.0463L165.954 37.2595L127.213 76H182V106H127.213L165.954 144.74L144.74 165.954L105.567 126.78V182H75.567V127.646L37.2602 165.953L16.047 144.74Z" fill="#FF4D00"/>
  </svg>
          </div>
          <h1>DEVELOPER</h1>
          <div className={styles.svgContainer}>
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="182" height="182" viewBox="0 0 182 182" fill="none">
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M16.047 144.74L54.7868 106H0V76H54.7868L16.047 37.2602L37.2602 16.047L75.567 54.3538V0H105.567V55.2198L144.74 16.0463L165.954 37.2595L127.213 76H182V106H127.213L165.954 144.74L144.74 165.954L105.567 126.78V182H75.567V127.646L37.2602 165.953L16.047 144.74Z" fill="#FF4D00"/>
  </svg>
          </div>
       
        </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


can't deploy with the error like this even though it doesn't affect anything in terms of visual or animation in the dev env.

Logs:
Error in the dev-enviroment (this still works after the browser has rendered it, everything is fine even server-console is saying window is undefined):
** ⨯ ReferenceError: window is not defined**
at webpack_require (C:\Users\HP\Documents\coding\portfolio-v4.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
at eval (./src/app/page.jsx:10:75)
at (ssr)/./src/app/page.jsx (C:\Users\HP\Documents\coding\portfolio-v4.next\server\app\page.js:162:1)
at Object.webpack_require [as require] (C:\Users\HP\Documents\coding\portfolio-v4.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
at JSON.parse ()
Error in the production, vercel enviroment (this failed to deploy):
ReferenceError: window is not defined
at 9948 (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/page.js:17:49975)
at Object.t [as require] (/vercel/path0/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:127)
at require (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:16:18490)
at I (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:94362)
at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:96668
at F._fromJSON (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:97106)
at JSON.parse ()
at O (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:94083)
at t (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:100582) {
digest: '3351242129'
}
Specs:
"dependencies": {
"gsap": "^3.12.5",
"locomotive-scroll": "^5.0.0-beta.13",
"next": "14.2.5",
"react": "^18",
"react-dom": "^18"
}
}
I've tried using all the methods in the official error documentation of nextjs which is https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error

I found the issue—LocomotiveScroll() version 5 was racing against the initial render, even when I put it in the useEffect() hook. I fixed it by using a dynamic import with "await import()" as recommended in React's documentation. Here's my updated page.jsx file.


 useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
      console.log('WINDOW IS UNREADABLE')
    } else{
      //dynamic import to fix the window issue
      const importLocomotiveScroll = async () => {
        const LocomotiveScroll = (await import("locomotive-scroll")).default;
        const locomotiveScroll = new LocomotiveScroll();
      };

      importLocomotiveScroll();
      console.log('WINDOW EXISTED')
    }
      
  }, []);



Have a good day! this works in NextJs 14 with LocomotiveScroll.v5
